# How to delete a persisted indexedDB databse?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

If a user has given permission for a web page to persist an indexedDB database through `navigator.storage.persist()`, how can the user later delete the database? In other words, in the following MDN example, how exactly is explicit user action performed?

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist)
  navigator.storage.persist().then(function(persistent) {
    if (persistent)
      console.log("Storage will not be cleared except by explicit user action");
    else
      console.log("Storage may be cleared by the UA under storage pressure.");
  });
```

Related to this question, if an extension that acts upon a local HTML file persists a database and the user later deletes that local HTML file, is there a way for the extension to programmatically remove the associated persisted database from browser memory, that is, wherever it is storing the SQLite file that is the database such that it does not take up space unnecessarily?

Thank you.

Comment: Same way you clean up cookies in browser control panel. Site data management allows clearing all or selectively clearing by site. Can do it in browser dev tools also

Comment: Thanks. If I give permission for a database to persist and then clear the site data it is deleted; however, it doesn't appear separately in the list to clear that url only. At least not for a local HTML file in Firefox.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by doesn't appear separately. In FF there is a Manage Data option that shows list of sites storing data. Perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, but the local URL doesn't appear there in the list of sites after the database is created and persisted. But, if the clear all option is selected, then it is deleted. The user cannot delete only the local URL unless delete data for all sites. That is, unless I'm doing something wrong,

Comment: Are you looking to give them the option to do it in your page perhaps? That's fairly easy with the API

Comment: I do give the option in the page; but since this extension acts on some local HTML pages and sets up a persisted database in them, I'd like to make sure that, if the user deletes the local file, that persisted database can be deleted without opening the page again, since it's no longer reachable.  I could inform the user that they need to do this manually but I've been unable to locate the local file in the Site Data as you mentioned. And I don't see how I could do it programmatically even if I tracked all the databases created by the extension and asked the user if any needed deleted. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say it's the browser who should clean up leftovers if the associated file was deleted. If it doesn't then I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: I don't think the browser can know that the user deleted a local HTML file that had a persisted database associated with it. It's the same as if a non-local page had a persisted database and the user doesn't visit the again for a year. Unless the user deletes it manually the browser keeps it for the next visit. Except in the local scenario, the local url can never be visited again because it has been deleted.